# match on or all items inside curly braces and map them to a given string

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match, curly-braces

I have the following problem:

For example, I have this virtual URL test/{parameter1}/{parameter2}/{parameter3}/

and I want to extract from the following real URLs the values matching the parameter names from the virtual URL and map them to the parameter names in an array:

/test/abc/def/ghi/
Should return the following result:

```
[
"paramter1" => "abc",
"paramter2" => "def",
"paramter3" => "ghi",
]
```

/test/abc/def/
Should return the following result:

```
[
"paramter1" => "abc",
"paramter2" => "def",
]
```

For this I have the following 2 functions. One to extract and one to map.

```
    public static function processUrl($virtualUrl, $realUrl)
    {
    $realUrlRegex = preg_replace_callback('~\{([^{}]+)\}~',
    function ($matches)
    {
      $repl = '([^)]+)';
      self::$tmp[] = $matches[1];
      return $repl;
    }
    , $virtualUrl);
    print_r(self::$tmp);
    $UrlArray = array();
    $matches = array();
    $realUrlRegex = str_replace('/', '\/', $realUrlRegex);

    if (preg_match("/^" . $realUrlRegex . "$/", $realUrl, $matches))
    {
      print_r($matches); 
      for ($i = 0; $i < count(self::$tmp); $i++)
      {
        if(isset($matches[$i + 1])){
          $UrlArray[self::$tmp[$i]] = $matches[$i + 1];
        }
      }
      $matches = array();
      self::$tmp = array();
      return $UrlArray;
    }
    self::$tmp = array();
    return false;
    }

    
  

    public function mapUrl($route, $request)
    { 
    $dynamicParameters = $route->getDynamicParameters() ;
    $mappedUrl = preg_replace_callback('/{{([^}]+)}}/', function ($m) use ($dynamicParameters) {
      return $dynamicParameters[$m[1]]; }, $request->getUrl());
    return $mappedUrl;
    }
```

For this I have the following 2 functions. One to extract and one to map.

For example 1 it works fine, but if one of the virtual parameters is missing in the real url, preg match does not return any results and the URL is not processed correctly.

Comment: Why not use `explode`? If you need a regex to find all parts between slashes after `/test/`, you may use `preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!\A)/|^/test/)\K[^/]+~', $request->getUrl(), $matches)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/esDKyO/1).

Comment: What input didn't provide the expect output, specifically